# Will google authentication tokens work after updating scopes for my project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api, google-authentication

I have created a project with my gmail id for my app. In that i have not set scope for calendar events. But for my app while authenticating i am using calendar scopes(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar). I started using this for more than 3 months. But now sometimes it is showing app is not verified in oAuth consent screen. So I have updated my domain details and verified the domain.

My question is, some set of users who are already authenticated to create event through my app. I was using their tokens to create events. Will these tokens work even after updating my scopes in oAuth consent screen? or do they need to authenticate again?

Comment: Google OAuth Access Tokens expire after 3600 seconds. Are also using the Refresh Token to grant new Access Tokens?

Comment: @JohnHanley, I am not asking about expire date of tokens. Since i made some changes on scopes and requested for domain verification will these tokens be rejected or shall i continue using the tokens. Do all my authenticated users need to authenticate again after my domain verification.

Comment: I did not provide you with an answer. I made a comment - the tokens expire and need to be reissued which means your question does not matter in one hour. I am not actually sure 100% but usually when you change anything with the Client OAuth, the users will need to reauthenticate. However, since I am not 100% certain I did not post an answer.